# Get difference types of JSON response Retrofit

Tags: java, android, rest, retrofit2

I have REST api which respond according to current state at the same path. Let's assume `/api/users` response with

```
{
  "status":200,
  "error":false,
  "users":["a","b"]
}
```

if user is authorised.
Else if user is not authorised it respond with `{"status":403,"error":true,"redirect":"url"}`. When defining Interface for api calls with Retrofit it needs the exact type of response object.

Ex:

```
@GET("users")
Call<List<User>> getUsers()
```

But here API server respond with different shapes of object. How to handle this type of situation?

Comment: Create a base class which is  extended by success response class and failure response calss. In API interface use base class. When actual response comes then check for error code and parse accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Opinion based answer**

A Base class

```
public class BaseResponse{
    int status;
    String error;
    ...
    ...
}
```

A success response class

```
public class SuccessResponse extends BaseResponse{
    String[] users;
    ...
    ...
}
```

A failure response class

```
public class FailureResponse extends BaseResponse{
    String redirect;
    ...
    ...
}
```

API interface

```
@GET("users")
Call<BaseResponse> getUsers()
```

When data arrives

```
if(response.code == 200)
    // Parse with SuccessResponse Class
else
    // Parse with FailureResponse class
```

Answer (score 0):

use this class as your model pojo

```
public class User {

@SerializedName("status")
@Expose
private int status;
@SerializedName("error")
@Expose
private String error;
@SerializedName("users")
@Expose
private String users;

public int getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(int status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public String getError() {
    return error;
}

public void setError(String error) {
    this.error = error;
}

public String getUsers() {
    return users;
}

public void setUsers(String users) {
    this.users = users;
}
```

}

and call this model in your retrofit as...

```
Call<List<User>> res = BaseUrlClass.yourInterfaceHere().getUsers();
    res.enqueue(new Callback<List<User>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<User>> call, Response<List<User>> response) {
            int stat;
            String err,uuser;
            List<User> a = response.body();
           for(int i = 0;i<a.size;i++){
                  User u = a.get(i);
                   stat = u.getStatus();
                   err = u.getError();
                   uuser = u.getUsers();

            if(stat == 200){
                   //do this
              } else{
                    //do this
                  }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<User>> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: But how to get "redirect":"url" from User class. It is not a property of user.

Comment: can u post your json?

Comment: See the question please. `{"status":403,"error":true,"redirect":"url"}` Here is the other response.