# How to set dynamically model to Retrofit requests?

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

In my application i want use **Retrofit2** library for requests and i want set **dynamically** response model, i don't want set model into `interface` model!
**For example :** 
**My interface method is :**

```
@GET("api/server?mode=supports")
Call<SupportListResponse> getSupport_List(@Header("jwt") String token);
```

I don't want set `SupportListResponse` into `Call<>` , i want set this model **dynamically** from `Activity`/`Fragment` class!

How can i set **general model** class **instead of** `SupportListResponse` ?

How can i it?

Comment: Create a BaseModel and let every model extend it. Use BaseModel here and then you can get it as your final model. I answered a similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50794523/get-difference-types-of-json-response-retrofit/50794644#50794644

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>You can use generic method:</s>

```
@GET("api/server?mode=supports")
<T> Call<T> getSupport_List(@Header("jwt") String token);
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html

**UPDATE:**
According to https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/2012, you cannot use generics because retrofit needs to know the return type.

You can try to specify result as okhttp3.ResponseBody

```
@GET("api/server?mode=supports")
Call<ResponseBody> getSupport_List(@Header("jwt") String token);
```

And parse it in your code.
You can look how it's done in retrofit:

for json, using Google's Gson:
https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/8b8887c139c4cf13072499bafe8bb94e06903ea2/retrofit-converters/gson/src/main/java/retrofit2/converter/gson/GsonResponseBodyConverter.java#L36

for protobuf, using Google's Protobuf:
https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/8b8887c139c4cf13072499bafe8bb94e06903ea2/retrofit-converters/protobuf/src/main/java/retrofit2/converter/protobuf/ProtoResponseBodyConverter.java#L37

Comment: Show me this error : `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Method return type must not include a type variable or wildcard: retrofit2.Call<T>` how can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Using Object instead

ex:

```
@GET("api/server?mode=supports")
Call<Object> getSupport_List(@Header("jwt") String token);
```

hope this helps